# Can someone help me convert this to VB

Tags: c#

I tried an online converter, but it sucks. Any help is appreciated.

```
// Set the event handler for when the application data object changes.
(Application.Current as ExecutionModelApplication.App).ApplicationDataObjectChanged +=
                    new EventHandler(MainPage_ApplicationDataObjectChanged);
```

Comment: There's some c# wizardry here that I can't understand. I only know the basic c# syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
AddHandler CType(Application.Current,ExecutionModelApplication.App).ApplicationDataObjectChanged, 
    AddressOf NameOfHandlerMethod
```

Event Handler:

```
Proctected Sub NameOfHandlerMethod(sender as Object, E as EventArgs)
  .
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
   AddHandler TryCast(Application.Current, ExecutionModelApplication.App).ApplicationDataObjectChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf MainPage_ApplicationDataObjectChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler TryCast(Application.Current,ExecutionModelApplication.App).ApplicationDataObjectChanged,_
AddressOf MainPage_ApplicationDataObjectChanged
```